# my minecraft keeps on crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I recently bought myself a Windows 10 gaming computer and I downloaded MC on it. It works until I try to open a world or server and crashes giving me this message:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 301]
[19:24:28] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Vek05
[19:24:28] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is <censored>)
[19:24:29] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[19:24:29] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[19:24:30] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[19:24:30] [Thread-4/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[19:24:30] [Thread-4/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[19:24:30] [Thread-4/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[19:24:30] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[19:24:31] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[19:24:42] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.9
[19:24:42] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[19:24:42] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[19:24:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 10%
[19:24:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 22%
[19:24:45] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 34%
[19:24:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 48%
[19:24:47] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 61%
[19:24:48] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 72%
[19:24:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[19:24:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 97%
[19:24:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 12, from 10
[19:24:51] [Server thread/INFO]: Vek05[local:E:0e11365e] logged in with entity id 236 at (244.5, 98.0, 265.5)
[19:24:51] [Server thread/INFO]: Vek05 joined the game
[19:24:55] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running 4073ms behind, skipping 81 tick(s)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe9ca0d76c, pid=9492, tid=7700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig9icd64.dll+0x56d76c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\vince\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid9492.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

What does it mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: You should also provide the information in those files, but preferably with a bit of edited text, this was a pain to read

Answer (score 3):

This error/crash is caused by outdated Intel graphics card drivers. You will need to update them here: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/ Source: [Here](https://bugs.mojang.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MC-94900)

Comment: maybe this is the problem     "Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows"

Comment: No, the problem is what I have said. The message about dumps will always appear on any crash unless the person has specifically enabled them

Comment: Actually it turned out i had to update my game driver.